# Entity Framework force single row table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

Using Entity Framework 4.1 code first and POCO entities in MVC3; I would like to create a single-row table called ActiveBlog, which has an id, and holds a reference to a blog table.

ActiveBlog
PK: ID, FK: BlogID

How can I define a table, both in the database and in my POCO entity, that is constraint to only hold one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a trigger in your database.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sqldatabaseengine/thread/FCC7CECA-CF2F-42E2-8E79-1DCB5A3B82EC

Answer (score 0):

You can't/shouldn't - you would/should have to check its row count every time.
Ideally you want to write this into your repository or whatever class you wrap this Ef object with.

Comment: Yes. A repository. I actually did end up doing like you have described. But it didn't feel quite right. Thank you.

Comment: You can (and prob should) validate on the server side  via a constraint, but your application logic should handle this scenario. It needs to know to update a single row or insert a new row.